# Need to decompose a column to multiple columns based on unique values in a table?

Tags: sql, excel, pivot, amazon-redshift

Please help me with suitable ways to do this in Excel and SQL/Redshift.

So suppose I have a table like :

[image: Original Table]

I want to decompose this column 5, to as many columns as unique values in that column and put corresponding value of column 6 in the rows. Basically I want only one row for unique [column1, column2, column3] pair. So, I want the result like :

[image: Required Table]

Comment: Please don't link to images of data.  Please copy the data in to your question and use the markdown control to format it.  This way we can see the data in the context of the question, the input and output next to each other, and copy the data in to an app such as SQL Fiddle if necessary.  Also, are you trying to do this in Excel or in RedShift?

Answer (score 1):

A simple SQL way to accomplish this would be to use `MAX()` together with `CASE`...

```
SELECT
  column1,
  column2,
  column3,
  column4,
  MAX(CASE WHEN column5 = 'val1' THEN column6 END)   AS val1,
  MAX(CASE WHEN column5 = 'val2' THEN column6 END)   AS val2,
  MAX(CASE WHEN column5 = 'val3' THEN column6 END)   AS val3
FROM
  yourTable
GROUP BY
  column1,
  column2,
  column3,
  column4
```

In the `CASE` expressions, if column5 doesn't match, the result of the `CASE` is implicitly `NULL`.

Then, in the `MAX()`, any `NULL` values are effectively ignored.

This causes the combination to pick the highest value of `column6` where `column5` is `val1` / `val2` / `val3`.  Assuming there is only one such match, it picks that one matching value.